# Adding pdf file to existing pdf collection using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I have 4-5 PDFs have that could have 2-3 pages each.  I then merge all the pdf together using iTextSharp. So it looks like 1122233444555 (each set of # represents a pdf.  The duplicating represents the pages) The whole set is the new PDF.

We have a requirement where after the pdfs have merged, we may need to insert another PDF (2 pages) in between 2 & 3.  How would I go about inserting after the last page of 2 and before the first page of 3? So it should now look like 1122266633444555.

We are not storing the # of pages so I don't want to rely on passing in the page numbers. Can I write some hidden file names in each page and use itextsharp to read the hidden information?  Then I can say add pdf 666 after the last page of 222.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by marking page 2 for post-processing using a [PdfPageLabels](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageLabels.html) object. [Some sample code](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextSharp/markPage.aspx). See the links in the first paragraph of the link to the sample code for another way to do this by adding hidden fields to the document.